# Error after altering xml custom feed by function

Tags: wordpress, parsing, xml-parsing

WHen using a plugin in wordpress to create a custom xml feed, i have the option to insert custom functions. For example, i want a different field when a customer enters a different delivery adress.

When executing i get the following error:

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in .../wp-content/plugins/wp-all-export-pro/libraries/WpaeXmlProcessor.php(510) : eval()'d code on line 1\n.
```

The function is as follow:

```
function get_order_item_lines( $skus = '', $qty = '', $id = '', $breedte = '', $lengte = '' ){
    $skus = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $skus);
    $xml = '';
    if ( !empty( $skus ) && is_array( $skus ) ){
        foreach ( $skus as $key => $sku ){
            $xml .= "**LT**item**GT**";
            $xml .= "**LT**EAN**GT**" . $sku . "**LT**/EAN**GT**";
            $xml .= "**LT**aantal**GT**" . (empty($qty[$key]) ? "" : $qty[$key]) . "**LT**/aantal**GT**";
            $xml .= "**LT**productmaatmat**GT**" . (empty($id) ? "" : $id) . "**LT**/productmaatmat**GT**";
            $xml .= "**LT**breedte**GT**" . (empty($breedte[$key]) ? "" : $breedte[$key]) . "**LT**/breedte**GT**";
            $xml .= "**LT**lengte**GT**" . (empty($lengte[$key]) ? "" : $lengte[$key]) . "**LT**/lengte**GT**";
            $xml .= "**LT**/item**GT**";
        }
    } else {
            $xml .= "**LT**item**GT**";
            $xml .= "**LT**EAN**GT**" . $skus . "**LT**/EAN**GT**";
            $xml .= "**LT**aantal**GT**" . ( empty( $qty ) ? "" : $qty ) . "**LT**/aantal**GT**";
            $xml .= "**LT**productmaatmat**GT**" . ( empty( $id ) ? "" : $id ) . "**LT**/productmaatmat**GT**";
            $xml .= "**LT**breedte**GT**" . ( empty($breedte) ? "" : $breedte ) . "**LT**/breedte**GT**";
            $xml .= "**LT**lengte**GT**" . ( empty($lengte) ? "" : $lengte ) . "**LT**/lengte**GT**";
            $xml .= "**LT**/item**GT**";
    }
    return $xml;
}
```

Im really searching where the error is. I know it is in this function, because when i remove this function, it does work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Making a quick search and not diving deep into the code (following the error) I can say that you have one less open parenthesis "(" that doesn't correspond with close parenthesis ")"

Comment: Yes i fount that too.... but i dont see any particulair error in the function. All parenthesis are opened and closed (or am i something missing here)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, mistake from my side. On the new domain, the fields breedte en lengte were not present (never created in the database). Therefore this error happened.

After placing one order with this specific dimensions, the code worked.

Thanks for your effort nevertheless!